# SQL Server database table column has parentheses in its name

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Power BI I am trying to use custom sql to query a SQL Server database. The problem is I want the average of a column but this column has parentheses in its name.

```sql
AVG(Storage(Date))
```

The strangely named column, `Storage(Date)` causes a syntax error. I tried putting column name in `[]` but still get the same syntax error.

Comment: Then you have other characters in the name as well perhaps a space.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no the name is exactly as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Use square brackets: `AVG([Storage(Date)]) `

Comment: If the square brackets don't work then this: `Storage(Date)` is not the name of the column.

Comment: @forpas My first guess was exactly this but it didn't work. I got the error: Operand data type varchar is invalid for avg operator.

Comment: So you are trying to get the average of a varchar column?

Comment: @forpas in fact the look of the data is decimal but the underlying type is varchar. I used cast but no luck yet. But this problem is irrelevant to my main question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you try this: `avg(cast([Storage(Date)] as decimal(20, 5)))`?

Comment: @forpas Yes, I used avg(cast(coalesce([Storage(Date)],0.0) as decimal(20, 5))) but no luck yet. Guess there are some strange data in the column that I am not taking into account.

Comment: @Hessam Please provide a screenshot of `SELECT * FROM table_name`

Comment: If you're on a relatively modern version of SQL Server try using `try_cast` instead of `cast`, i.e.: `avg(coalesce(try_cast([Storage(Date)] as decimal(20,5)), 0.0))`

Comment: have you tried replacing the parentheses? SUBSTITUTE(Date, '(',  ?